# How to get a substring with .net micro framework?

Tags: string, substring, .net-micro-framework

Using .Net Micro Framework, how do I get the value of "socket_id" out of the following string:

```
{"event":"pusher:connection_established","data":"{"socket_id":"2475.1248660"}"}
```

Comment: Did you try to get socket_id value by regular expression?

Answer (score 2):

It's not exactly getting a substring, but have you considered using the [netduino Helpers library](http://netduinohelpers.codeplex.com/). It has some lightweight helpers for .NET MF (including a JSON parser).